# Combine two arrays with prepend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following two arrays:

```
months = ["2017_01", "2017_02", "2017_03"] 
codes = ["abc","efg"]
```

I want to combine them into one array as follows:

```
result = ["abc_2017_01", "abc_2017_02", "abc_2017_03",
          "efg_2017_01", "efg_2017_02", "efg_2017_03"]
```

I've tried various things, but keep ending up with values like abc_efg_2017_01 etc. Each of the original arrays can be any size, I've just used small arrays to illustrate the problem.

Can anyone suggest a nice succinct way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
codes.product(months).map { |vals| vals.join('_') }
#⇒ [
#  [0] "abc_2017_01",
#  [1] "abc_2017_02",
#  [2] "abc_2017_03",
#  [3] "efg_2017_01",
#  [4] "efg_2017_02",
#  [5] "efg_2017_03"
# ]
```

**NB** check comments for cleaner approaches.

Comment: You don't need to splat `vals` here: `codes.product(months).map { |*vals| vals.join('_') } == codes.product(months).map { |vals| vals.join('_') } #=> true`

Comment: @MichaelKohl I know; I am positive that splat makes it more succinct here.

Comment: explaination, maybe?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how an extraneous character makes something more 'succinct', but it's your answer :-)

Comment: @max here `flat_map` is redundant, `map` is sufficiently enough. Basically, that solution is exactly the same as mine.

Comment: The splat wraps each pair in an extra array, i.e. it converts `["abc", "2017_01"]` to `[["abc", "2017_01"]]`. It only works because `join` flattens nested arrays. You should remove the splat.

Comment: Indeed. Finally have the splat removed.  

Comment: A slight variation `codes.product(['_'],months).map(&:join)`.

Comment: Another point-free version: `codes.product(months).map(&'%s_%s'.method(:%))` ;-)

Comment: @Stefan rofl. I fear once you’ll mistakenly bring smth like that into your real codebase and I will become _persona non grata_ in Bremen.

Answer (score 3):

```
codes.flat_map do |c|
  months.map { |m| "#{c}_#{m}" }
end
```

Output:

```
=> ["abc_2017_01", "abc_2017_02", "abc_2017_03", "efg_2017_01", "efg_2017_02", "efg_2017_03"]
```

Comment: Good idea. Thanks @mudasobwa

Answer (score 1):

Also, `Matrix` could be the rescue:

```
require 'matrix'
Matrix.build(codes.size, months.size) { |row, col| "#{codes[row]}_#{months[col]}" }
      .to_a.flatten
#=> ["abc_2017_01", "abc_2017_02", "abc_2017_03", 
#    "efg_2017_01", "efg_2017_02", "efg_2017_03"]
```

Or the same with arrays:

```
Array.new(codes.size) do |i| 
  Array.new(months.size) { |j| "#{codes[i]}_#{months[j]}"}
end.flatten
#=> ["abc_2017_01", "abc_2017_02", "abc_2017_03", 
#    "efg_2017_01", "efg_2017_02", "efg_2017_03"]
```